# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rt'

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting this error even though the attribute 'rt' is there in my dataframe. It was working before and I am not sure why it's not working now. Any ideas?

This is how my code looks:

```
path1 = '/home/data/1-23.csv'
file1 = pd.read_csv(path1,skipinitialspace=True, index_col=None)
df1 = file1[~file1.rt.isna()]
df1 = file1[~file1.comment2.isna()]

df1 = df1[['word','value','color','rt']]
print(df1.head())
```

This is how the data looks:

```
resultstime,ipaddress,controller,numberitem,innernumber,label,latingp,penntype,pennname,parameter,value,eventime,word,color,correct,rt,comment2                                                             
1619906522,529a13d061460b9dd2ecdcd4dcd0b118,PennController,43,0,experimental-trial,NULL,PennController,44,_Trial_,Start,1619906424186,CHOQUE, green, v,1353,NULL                                                                
1619906522,529a13d061460b9dd2ecdcd4dcd0b118,PennController,43,0,experimental-trial,NULL,Text,word,Print,NA,1619906424186,CHOQUE, green, v,1353,NULL                                                             
1619906522,529a13d061460b9dd2ecdcd4dcd0b118,PennController,43,0,experimental-trial,NULL,Key,keypress,PressedKey,V,1619906425542,CHOQUE, green, v,1353,Wait success
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide the csv file? This works fine for me with the example.

Anyway, you can achieve what you want simply using:

```
df.dropna(subset=['rt', 'comment2'])[['word','value','color','rt']]
```

Comment: for some reason that doesn't work for me, it says: in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
KeyError: ['rt', 'comment2'] . The data that I provided in my question shows a sample of the data in the csv

Comment: Well, there is no error for me, that's why I requested the full csv. There is nothing wrong otherwise.

Comment: I'm trying to upload it but I think the data is too large for this website https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARI1poByp4jl0jdT76ByC_qOpwDg30G9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see what's wrong. Your csv file is invalid, all lines are quoted which forces it to be a single field, and there is indeed no "rt" column. You have to remove all quotes from the file. If using linux you can do `tr -d \" <1-23.csv >1-23_fixed.csv`

Comment: This is a good example why it is important to provide datasets ;)